# Problem in typecasting of floats using scanners

Tags: java, casting, java.util.scanner

I am not able to execute the following program. it is unable to load the main class

```
package com.seed.util;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class cast2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        float m;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        m=sc.nextInt();
        int n;
        n=(int) m;
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you running the code?

Comment: It executes fine on me. Can you compile it, or a runtime exception was thrown? Please state your error message.

Comment: Are you sure you are running the same file? The code looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the line

```
m=sc.nextInt();
```

with

```
m=sc.nextFloat();
```

It will definitely execute.